# Titanium API call - HTTP error

Tags: ios, ember.js, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am having a website which contains vendors page. In webpage when user clicks on particular company all data relevant to vendors returns but when vendor api is called it passes a variable name x-access-token which is generally data returned when user logs in. Please have a look as following image to get idea.

[image]

Now I want to use the same api in my Titanium application and get all vendors in particular company. For which following mentioned code has been written by me

```
var url = "http://www.www.com/vendor?company=demo";

var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function(e) {
        // function called in readyState DONE (4)
        Ti.API.info('onload called, readyState = '+this.readyState);
        Ti.API.info("Status " + xhr.status);
    },
    onerror: function(e) {
        // function called in readyState DONE (4)
        Ti.API.info('onerror called, readyState = '+this.readyState);
        Ti.API.info("Status " + xhr.status);
        Ti.API.info('ERROR - '+e.error);
    },
    ondatastream: function(e) {
        // function called as data is downloaded
        Ti.API.info('ondatastream called, readyState = '+this.readyState);
        Ti.API.info("Status " + xhr.status);
    },
    onsendstream: function(e) {
        // function called as data is uploaded
        Ti.API.info('onsendstream called, readyState = '+this.readyState);
        Ti.API.info("Status " + xhr.status);
    },
    onreadystatechange: function(e) {
        switch(this.readyState) {
            case 0:
                // after HTTPClient declared, prior to open()
                // though Ti won't actually report on this readyState
                Ti.API.info('case 0, readyState = '+this.readyState);
                break;
            case 1:
                // open() has been called, now is the time to set headers
                Ti.API.info('case 1, readyState = '+this.readyState);
                break;
            case 2:
                // headers received, xhr.status should be available now
                Ti.API.info('case 2, readyState = '+this.readyState);
                break;
            case 3:
                // data is being received, onsendstream/ondatastream being called now
                Ti.API.info('case 3, readyState = '+this.readyState);
                break;
            case 4:
                // done, onload or onerror should be called now
                Ti.API.info('case 4, readyState = '+this.readyState);
                break;
        }
    },
    timeout:7000  /* in milliseconds */
});

xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.setRequestHeader('x-access-token', userToken);
xhr.send();
```

And following is output for the same.

```
case 1, readyState = 1
case 3, readyState = 3
case 4, readyState = 4
ondatastream called, readyState = 4
Status 403
case 4, readyState = 4
onsendstream called, readyState = 4
Status 403
ondatastream called, readyState = 4
Status 403
onerror called, readyState = 4
Status 403
ERROR - HTTP error
```

I am getting HTTP error. Am i setting header for x-access-token in wrong way or there exists any alternate way in order to perform the same ?. Can any one help me out with this ? Any suggestion regarding the same would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That seems OK. Replace the URL with a http://requestb.in one so you can see the exact request.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. I tried changing url created from requestbin. and there I am able to get request header.                 X-Access-Token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhZG1pbiIsImV4cCI6MTQ3NjM1NTY2NjEwMn0.rVEeltZxOY5wFIskL0J95vltv-tOHeVsSUVMopVQ8pg". But i have passed request header x-access-token. One more thing I noticed is that while api call from website is done it gives me reply x-access-token:eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhZG1pbiIsImV4cCI6MTQ3NjM1NjM1MjAxOX0.nm6lZN9jUnFBfe_0ZeI0JbjquljOu4uVbar1ar1ovpU. Is it going to make difference. ?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue by checking passing the query string i.e `company=demo` after stringifying the same. As well as userToken which was passed in setRequestHeader as below ie. `xhr.setRequestHeader('x-access-token', userToken);` was passed as string due to which I was getting `X-Access-Token : "randomtoken"`in http://requestb.in while when webservice is called from my website it was simply passed displaying `X-Access-Token : randomtoken` So converted token type to object while storing as well as fetching  i.e `var userToken = Ti.App.Properties.getObject("userToken");`. It might help some one.